# Sharepoint: How to get file in specific folder by custom field

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

My sharepoint list (Documents Library) has custom text field "MyCustomId";

I have a folder inside the list and bunch of files in the folder.

How do I get specific item (file) in the folder, e.g. where MyCustomId="abc"?

```
    List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
    Folder folder  = list.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl(folderName);
    ctx.Load(folder);
    await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();

    var items = list.GetItems(??);       
    ctx.Load(items);
    //? or
    var files= folder.Files??.Where()
    ctx.Load(files);
    await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `ctx.Load` and specify `where` clause and which fields should be returned. It returns `FileCollection`.

```
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
Folder folder  = list.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl(folderName);
ctx.Load(folder);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();

// load files
var files = folder.Files;
ctx.Load(files, files => files
            .Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields, f => f.Name)
            .Where(f => f.ListItemAllFields.FieldValuesAsText["MyCustomId"] == "abc"));
await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
// iterate through the files
```

Second option is to create a caml query. It returns `ListItemCollection`.

```
var camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyCustomId'/><Value Type='Text'>abc</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
ctx.Load(listItems);
await ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

Comment: The second example misses filter to specific folder. This is achievable using FileDirRef field: `<Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/sites/mySite/{listName}/{folderName}</Value></Eq>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research and testing, you can use CAML Query to get the specified file:

```
var q = new CamlQuery();
q.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyCustomId' /><Value Type='Text'>abc</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
var r = list.GetItems(q);
ctx.Load(r);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Does not work for two reasons. First, in CAML, View element must have `Scope='RecursiveAll'`. Second, it doesn't filter to specific folder